# Routing POST Request Data JSON to View/Controller (node.js)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, post

Basically, I'm working on a local server (http://localhost:3000/) that receives a post request from another server like so:

```
return requestLib.post({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/test',
    timeout: 120000,
    json: true,
    body: {
        user: user,
        proposal: proposal
    }
});
```

and I want to use the json from this post request on my local server to create views for the json received from this post request. Here is what I'm currently doing in my routes.js file on my localhost server:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', req.body);
    res.end();
});
```

My question is how do I use this json received as scope in my controllers and views on my local server? I'm extremely new to angular and node as you can probably tell so apologies if this is a stupid question/doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

You may don't want to return a rendered view from POST request when using angularjs, because angularjs has it's own template system. POST requests usually using for data saving operations or updates.

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body
    var proposal = data.proposal
    // some db operation etc...
    res.send("Success")
});
```

Angularjs and node.js are completely different things.

Comment: Hmm ok, that's what I was beginning to think. Thank you Ozgur